# If I present a ViewController programmatically without using a Navigation Controller, does the new VC "replace" the old one, or does it stack on top?

Tags: ios, viewcontroller, swift5

I'm new to iOS.

I have an app where the path through the app can vary depending on the configuration I fetch from an API. Because of this, I don't use segues because I would need to create a segue from each ViewController (VC) to EVERY other VC. It creates a mess of segues that I don't want. So Instead I navigate from screen to screen like this:

```
func navigate(to viewController: String) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: K.mainStoryBoard, bundle: nil)
    let nextVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: viewController)
    self.present(nextVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

My question is this: If I would have embedded my VCs in a NavigationController I know it would have created a stack. When I get to the last screen I would call `func popToRootViewController(animated: Bool) -> [UIViewController]?` and start from the beginning. However, I don't use a NavigationController. So, does that mean that when I present the next VC it replaces the previous one or does it stack on top of the previous one? I'm trying to prevent memory leaks so I want to make sure I don't keep stacking the VCs on top of each other until my app runs out of memory and crashes.

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

So, in my final VC I created an unwind segue. And I call it like this: `performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToMain", sender: self)`

and In my first VC (the initial VC in my app) I write this:

```
 @IBAction func unwind( _ seg: UIStoryboardSegue) {

 }
```

Everything works fine the first trip through the app. The last VC unwinds back to the fist VC. The problem is now that when I try to run through the app again (starting from VC 1 and then going to the next one) I now get this error:

```
MyApp[71199:4203602] [Presentation] Attempt to present <MyApp.DOBViewController: 0x1038760c0> on <MyApp.ThankYouViewController: 0x112560c30> (from <MyApp.ThankYouViewController: 0x112560c30>) whose view is not in the window hierarchy.
```

To make sense of this, DOBViewController would be the second VC I want to go to from the MainVC. ThankYouViewController is my last VC. It looks as if it isn't completely removed from the stack. Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a Navigation Controller? If you're thinking about needing Segues, don't... You can push/pop controllers onto the Nav stack programmatically --- no Segues needed.

Comment: @DonMag how to hide the Navigation Controller's header?

Comment: You can use `navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)`

Comment: I embedded the first VC in a NavigationController and in the final VC I call this: print(self.view.window?.rootViewController?.navigationController == nil).....but the navigationController always returns nil ‍♂️

Comment: Why would you do that? If you don't want to *ever* show the navigation bar, use a Navigation Controller with `MainVC` as the root VC. In `MainVC`'s `viewDidLoad()` hide the navigation bar. Use code to **push** `DOBViewController` onto the navigation stack. Then use code (in `DOBViewController`) to **push** `ThankYouViewController` onto the navigation stack. Then use code (in `ThankYouViewController`) to **popToRootViewController**.

Comment: @DonMag.....that's what I'm doing. I hide the navigationController in viewDidLoad on the MainVC like this: self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false) It works fine. popToRootViewController does nothing because the navigationController returns nil

Comment: Take a look at the answer I just posted. That should make things clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simple, basic example...

The controllers are setup in Storyboard, each with a single button, connected to the corresponding `@IBAction`.

The `DOBViewController` has its Storyboard ID set to "dobVC".

The `ThankYouViewController` has its Storyboard ID set to "tyVC".

`MainVC` is embedded in a navigation controller (in Storyboard) and the navigation controller is set to **Initial View Controller**:

```
class MainVC: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    }
    
    @IBAction func pushToDOB(_ sender: Any) {
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dobVC") as? DOBViewController {
            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
    
}

class DOBViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBAction func pushToTY(_ sender: Any) {
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tyVC") as? ThankYouViewController {
            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
    
}

class ThankYouViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBAction func popToRoot(_ sender: Any) {
        navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: so is it because I'm not calling navigationController?.pushViewController...? Instead you can see how I'm adding my VCs above. In the MainVC I create a map of the path the user must take. I store storyboardIDs in an array and then traverse them using a helper class. Anyway, I call self.present instead of navigationController?.pushViewController. I will try to figure out a way to switch it up and use this instead.

Comment: that worked! Thank you for staying with me! I had to change the way I pushed the VCs onto the stack.

Answer (score 2):

**does that mean that when I present the next VC it replaces the previous one or does it stack on top of the previous one?**

> The new one stacks on top of the previous one.
>
> When you present a view controller, like
>
> ```
> self.present(nextVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
> ```
>
> The one you called `.present` on (`self` in this case) becomes [`presentingViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621430-presentingviewcontroller) for the `nextVC` instance.
>
> The one you presented (`nextVC` in this case) becomes [`presentedViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621407-presentedviewcontroller) for the `self` instance.

Comment: can you give me any insight with my edit?